# How to set Key in Stream cloud function

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using stream cloud stream in order to receive and publish events to kafka
I also use the functional programing model.

Say I have this bean definition:

```
@Bean
public Function<InputMsg,OutputMsg> handle(){
//do some calculation that returns OutputMsg
}
```

How can I controlor the key of the message? that is I want to send OutputMsg event back to kafka but I don't know how to control the key , only the value (OutputMsg in my example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Function<Message<InputMsg>, Message<OutputMsg>>` instead.

In the inbound message, the key is in `msg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY)`; to set the key in the outbound message, set `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY`.